# From SQl to Laravel Query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

I have this SQL query but had no idea how to write it in Laravel Query Builder

```
select state_id, state_name, sum(inactifs) as inactifs, sum(actifs) as actifs, 
sum(inactifs) + sum(actifs) as total
 from
(
select distinct s.id as state_id, s.name as state_name, u.id as user_id,
case when uga.id is null then 1 else 0 end as inactifs,
case when uga.id is null then 0 else 1 end as actifs
 from users u
inner join states s on u.state_id = s.id
left join user_group_affiliations uga on uga.user_id = u.id
and (uga.active = 1 and (uga.start_date is null or uga.start_date <= now()) and (uga.end_date is null or uga.end_date >= now()))
) quer group by state_id;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use DB::raw()

```
$users = DB::select(DB::raw("YOUR QUERY AS IT IS"));
```

With Query Builder - You can try something like this..

```
DB::query()->fromSub(function($main_query){
$main_query->from('users')
->select(
    DB::raw('distinct s.id as state_id, s.name as state_name, u.id as user_id, 
        case when uga.id is null then 1 else 0 end as inactifs,
        case when uga.id is null then 0 else 1 end as actifs
    ')
)
->join('states as s', 'u.state_id', '=', 's.id')
->leftJoin('user_group_affiliations as uga', 'uga.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->where('uga.active', 1)
->where(function($query){
    return $query->whereNull('uga.start_date')
                ->orWhere('uga.start_date' '<=' date_create())
})
->where(function($query){
    return $query->whereNull('uga.end_date')
                ->orWhere('uga.end_date' '>=' date_create())
})->groupBy('u.state_id') }, "quer")->get();
```

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: While possible, this bypasses a lot of useful Laravel functionality. It's typically better to properly migrate code to use Eloquent (or Fluent if it's not related to actual models) if at all possible.

Comment: @Gopal Panadi **thanks mate! got it working**    `0 => {#957 ▼
    +"state_id": "1"
    +"state_name": "تونس 1"
    +"inactifs": "3188"
    +"actifs": "45"
    +"total": "3233"
  }
  1 => {#964 ▼
    +"state_id": "2"
    +"state_name": "تونس 2"
    +"inactifs": "1365"
    +"actifs": "32"
    +"total": "1397"
  } ... `

Comment: No issue @LaadhariAmine . Still got -1 :D

Comment: When suggesting the use of `DB::raw` you should also emphasize the risk of SQL injection and encourage the use of **bindings** when any user input gets used in the query. Keep in mind that some novice programmers that stumble across your answer, will be oblivious to any risks they are exposing themselves when you offer such a short answer.